# Latex installation with tl fails

Tags: software-installation, latex

I'm trying to install latex on Ubuntu 16.04 with `./install-tl`
During installation it failes with:

```
TLUtils::check_file: removing /tmp/LPVwm0sGpG/NN2AQTZA2b/newpx.tar.xz, sizes differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=1463012, arg=1462980
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
Installation failed.
```

How can I fix this? And can I somehow use the installation log to restart installing from where it failed, or do I have to install all the same files again?

Comment: Complete answers about this are here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321650/texlive-installation-aborted-after-hours-of-installation-restarting-without-dup

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Latex community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX) specify:

> - TeX Live
>
> The preferred LaTeX distribution is the one that comes with TeX Live.
>   This is a general TeX distribution that is actively maintained by the
>   TeX Users Group.

You can use the information from [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/16/install-tex-live-2016-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/) and install Tex Live:

Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run command to add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive
```

run command to install or upgrade to Tex Live 2016:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install texlive-full
```

You may install a text editor for Tex Live, such as Kile, TeXMaker, JLatexEditor. The PPA contains an update version of TeXworks that can be installed via command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install texworks
```

How to Restore:

It’s always easy to uninstall Tex Live 2016 and downgrade to the stock version in official Ubuntu repositories by running command:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/texlive
```